# Did the Romans have a Latin name for their domestic peristylia?

Tags: greek, terminology, architecture

A typical upper- and probably also middle-class Roman house in the classical age contained a *peristylium* or *peristylum*, or so I was told. I wonder why they used a Greek word for such a standard Roman architectural feature. Did they also have a Latin term for it? Or was the feature adopted from Greek architecture?

Bonus question: if the construction was borrowed from the Greeks, when did this happen, and what did Roman houses look like before?

[image: Origin of picture: https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/a/a3/Brogi%2C_Carlo_%281850-1925%29_-_Pompei_-_Domus_Vettiorum_-_Veduta_del_peristilio_-_n._9711_-_ca._1896.jpg]

Answer (score 10, accepted):

> "The early Italian house consisted only of the *atrium* and the surrounding rooms, with, in most cases, a small garden at the back....  Out of the small plot at the back of the early house developed the *peristylium*, a garden surrounded by colonnades on to which rooms opened on all sides,... The *peristylium*, both in general appearance and in name, reproduced the men's room of a Greek house. Whilst the names of the front rooms of a Roman house are Italian (sic) (*atrium,fauces, alae, tablinum*)  those of the back are Greek (*peristylium, triclinium, oecus, exhedra*)"

*Rome: It's people, life and customs,*  Ugo Enrico Paoli, 1940, trans. R. D. Macnaghten, English version 1958.

**Comment and link incorporated as suggested by @Cerberus**

This link discusses the House of the Surgeon and the architectural development mentioned :-

https://sites.google.com/site/ad79eruption/pompeii/regio-vi/reg-vi-ins-1/house-of-the-surgeon

L&S give this as the derivation of *peristylium*  :-

> **peristylium** The Greek adjective περίστυλος is applied either to a court surrounded by colonnades on the inside, or to a building surrounded by them on the outside, as a temple. It is then used alone, in all three genders, with a substantive understood, for a court with colonnades: hence the Latin peristylum, or more commonly the substantive form peristylium. It is especially used for the courts of a Greek dwellinghouse, and for that introduced into Roman houses in imitation of them.

Comment: That's interesting. So do you think the Romans adopted their peristylia entirely from the Greeks and that structure and name arrived together?

Comment: @Cerberus - that's always been my understanding, although I'm afraid I can't give dates/references. In the work quoted, The House of the Surgeon, Pompeii, is offered as an example of an early Roman house, with a simple, asymmetrical,   *hortus* at the back. But I'm no expert!

Comment: OK I'll keep that theory in mind. Some magnificent mosaics in that house, incidentally!

Comment: @Cerberus I suspect the process was gradual, in fact, a bit like showing off your new smart watch, to show you're a) fashionable and b) can afford it!  ;)

Comment: Hah, how common! *sniffs*

Comment: Good addition! It does suggest that it was only introduced by the Greeks and it did not have a name in Latin before (nor after). I do wonder whether the Romans used some other kind of colonnade in their houses, before the adoption of the Greek peristylum?

Comment: @Cerberus It appears not, the various "orders" were borrowed (and adapted) by the Romans from the Greeks. AFAIK, the iconic Roman structure is the arch, resting on a fairly basic (non-columnar) pier.  PS thanks for tidying up my answer!  See https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Classical_order